# Which Network bonding mode gives better performance

Tags: networking, bonding

I have 2 ethernet interfaces eth0 and eth1. My goal is to use same ip for both interfaces.
I tried

```
Balance Round Robin- poor bandwidth performance observed
Active backup - Only one interface working
```

Which bonding mode gives similar performance when compared to no network bonding is used.
I don't need load balancing and fault tolerance. I just need single ip for 2 interfaces without any performance drop

Comment: Probably you need **bridge** instead of bonding?

Comment: Please elaborate your setup a bit more. Where are those interfaces connected to? What is the purpose of having one IP there?